# How do you fix sentence spacing on extracted plain text from HTML?

Tags: php, html, parsing, whitespace, simpledom

I'm pulling articles from specific URLs for conversion to sentences, but the text body has a random behavior of eliminating whitespace between some sentences resulting in:

```
Jane went to the store.She bought a dog. The dog was very friendly.It had no teeth.
```

Some of my text is stock symbols (AZ.GAN) etc. So I can't simply insert a space between all periods which have no adjacent whitespace.

```
Jane bought several shares of (TY.JPN). She lost all her cash money."Arg!" She cried.
```

The above example would destroy the stock symbol variable.

Curious if anyone knows the cause of this. I have tried several HTML and DOM. I use Simple_DOM to grab the plaintext. Although, I get the same result if I do it manually, or with any other parsing engine.

Comment: This doesn't sound right... do you have a sample URL for the source data? Or a short snippet (with markup) where this is happening? I'm assuming it doesn't display that way in a browser (if it does, it's GIGO)

Comment: If is the case of a line break PHP [nl2br()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) should help. Take a look at [htmlspecialchars()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) and
[htmlentities()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Comment: I can't access the markup, it's preprocessed through the Simple DOM object functions, which I've tried to manipulate without success. Plain text is obtained file_get_html('url')->plaintext. Not sure what it loses in the process which causes the erratic spacing. Could be a wordwrap artifact.

Comment: @Alix: [Garbage In, Garbage Out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_In,_Garbage_Out) :)

Comment: @sarnold: Oh, cool. Didn't knew there was an acronym for that! =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't have an approach for your specific question, but is it possible that the missing space between sentences is actually a linebreak (e.g. \n) that your text viewer (whatever it is) isn't showing you?

Perhaps try something like this just to make sure

`var articleContent = ... // get content

articleContent = articleContent.replace(/\n/g, ' NEW LINE ');`

Comment: Using Simple_DOM to pull plain text from urls. PHP. I can do it manually by stripping tags/CSS/HTML, but get the same result. Spacing random. I'll try the newline trick and get back - thanks

Comment: No, stripping the \n doesn't work - still with random spacing.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing:

```
$str = trim(preg_replace('~([(].+?[.])\s(.+?[)])~', '$1$2', str_replace('.', '. ', $str)));
```

Comment: Hmm that script is promising, but it obliterated my text and the behavior of my delimiters. The stock symbols vanished. Quotes became replaced by parentheses. Unfortunately, I have to way to access the HTML markup, because it is processed through the Simple DOM Object.

Comment: @user723220: We can work on it... =) Can you see any differences in the spacing? Also, if you could post the output of the following snippet it would help immensely: `echo implode('|', array_map('ord', str_split($yourString)));`.

Comment: I get a stream of thousands of numbers from that `10|32|115|97|105|100|44|32|97|110|100|32|97|116|32|108|101|97|115|116|32|49|55|32|112|101|111|112|108|101|32|119|101|114|101|32|107|10`

Comment: I looked at the source HTML. After most sentences this code `</p><span id="midArticle_8"></span><p>` appears. Must be the culprit. It must be getting stripped and leaving "" instead of " ". I contacted the author of Simple_DOM, to see if he had any thoughts on finding where this parsing happens in the simple_dom_php. Problem is it's all done cleverly through objects, so you can't tell what is what.

Comment: The above preg_replace seems to have no effect. It may be reducing some of the stuck sentences, but other articles not at all.

Comment: @user723220: Yup, your problem has nothing to do with control chars, I assumed this because you mentioned you were using Simple_DOM to get plain text URLs, but apparently no. Somehow, Simple_DOM is messing the HTML markup, which makes it very unreliable to trust `strip_tags()` to preserve the content and work around it. As for the spacing, it must be coming from UA or custom CSS styles. My suggestion is that you quit using Simple_DOM and code what you need yourself, or you can `$str = str_replace('</p><span id="midArticle_8"></span><p>', ' ', $str)` but that's kinda hacky...

Comment: I'm going to write a script which turns all "." into ". " unless they are within parentheses.